# Python scrape, skipping a <tr> tag and row

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Scraping a webpage and encountering an "IndexError: list index out of range"
pretty sure it's because a row in the table I am scraping is using  as a header - http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3022-mfsctrscan-moneyflow-20161205.html?mod=mdc_pastcalenda

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.today()
url = "http://www.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3022-mfsctrscan-moneyflow-  20161205.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar"
date_time = urlopen(url.format(date=date.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
address = url
print 'Retrieving information from: ' + address
print '\n'
soup = BeautifulSoup (requests.get(address).content, "lxml")
div_main = soup.find('div', {'id': 'column0'})
table_one = div_main.find('table')
rows = table_one.findAll('tr')
if len(soup.findAll('tr')) > 0:
rows = rows[2:]
#print rows
for row in rows:
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    name = cells[0].get_text()
    last = cells[1].get_text()
    chg = cells[2].get_text()
    pct_chg = cells[3].get_text()
    money_flow = cells[4].get_text()
    tick_up = cells[5].get_text()
    tick_down = cells[6].get_text()
    up_down_Ratio = cells[7].get_text()
    money_flow = cells[8].get_text()
    tick_up = cells[9].get_text()
    tick_down = cells[10].get_text()
    up_down_Ratio = cells[11].get_text()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intermediate rows with single cells like "Dow Jones U.S. Total Stock Market Sectors" is the reason you are having this error.

But, instead, why don't you pre-define a list of headers and dynamically create a dictionary from the values of the "data" rows zipping with the list of headers:

```
rows = soup.select('div#column0 table tr')[2:]

headers = ['name', 'last', 'chg', 'pct_chg',
           'total_money_flow', 'total_tick_up', 'total_tick_down', 'total_up_down_ratio',
           'block_money_flow', 'block_tick_up', 'block_tick_down', 'block_up_down_ratio']
for row in rows:
    # skip non-data rows
    if row.find("td", class_="pnum") is None:
        continue

    print(dict(zip(headers, [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all('td')])))
```

Comment: thank you - I believe this will make it easier to store the values in the future

Answer (score 1):

```
div_main = soup.find('div', {'id': 'column0'})
table_one = div_main.find('table')

# to id the right row
def target_row(tag):
    is_row = len(tag.find_all('td')) > 5
    row_name = tag.name == 'tr'
    return is_row and row_name

rows = table_one.find_all(target_row)
for row in rows:
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    name = cells[0].get_text()
    last = cells[1].get_text()
    chg = cells[2].get_text()
    pct_chg = cells[3].get_text()
    money_flow = cells[4].get_text()
    tick_up = cells[5].get_text()
    tick_down = cells[6].get_text()
    up_down_Ratio = cells[7].get_text()
    money_flow = cells[8].get_text()
    tick_up = cells[9].get_text()
    tick_down = cells[10].get_text()
    up_down_Ratio = cells[11].get_text()
```

you can use a function that return a bool as find's parameter, in this way, you code is much clean and maintainable.

Comment: Thank you - would you happen to know how to use datetime to scrape date-dynamic URLS to get data back to some range i.e. 20000101?